# How to write django form to a text file

Tags: django, django-forms

I m creating a django site (using django forms) that lets users subscribe their email. How do I get that email into a text file? Currently I have a cron job that runs a python script sending an email to all subscribers every morning. Is this the best way to do this or there is some built-in functionalities in django-forms that I can use?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you have a list of users from their email address saved into the database, and want to save that list to a text file?

Well you could go into `./manage.py shell` and type something like this:

```
# I assumed the email addresses are in User.email; modify as needed to conform to your model.

with open('email.txt','w') as f:
    for u in User.objects.all(): 
        f.write(u.email + '\n')
```

You could also write a management command to do this:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/

or create a simple view & template that creates a text file with all your email addresses in a list.  Though for the sake of your users not being spammed password protect this, and don't make this publicly accessible.  Something simple like (that is not private) should work:

urls.py:

```
from django.views.generic.list_detail import object_list
urlpatterns = patterns('', 
                       (r'^full_emails/$', 'object_list', {'template': 'template/text.txt', 'queryset'=User.objects.all()}
)
```

template/text.txt:

```
{% for user in object_list %}
   {{ user.email }}
{% endfor %}
```